# How to get [data-value] from parent element after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code structure looks like this:

```
<div id="calendar" data-calendar="0">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="nav_prev" data-calendar-nav="prev">
            <div class="nav_prev" data-calendar-nav="prev">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I really don't know how after click on `.nav_prev` or `.nav_next` get the `data-calendar` value (in this example 0 ) from `#calendar`. I know I should use `.parent()` but I cant figure out how to do this.

For now I have only that JS code:

```
$(document).on("click","#calendar .head .nav_prev, #calendar .head .nav_next",function(){
    if( $(this).attr('data-calendar-nav') == 'prev')
    {
        console.log('prev');
    }
    if( $(this).attr('data-calendar-nav') == 'next')
    {
        console.log('next');
    }
})
```

Comment: you are missing closing tags for div.

Comment: @ Milind Anantwar Yes

Comment: Problem solved. I used `closest` function. $(this).closest( "#calendar" ).attr('data-calendar')

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest()` to get to the parent and `data()` to get the data attribute:

```
$(document).on("click","#calendar .head .nav_prev, #calendar .head .nav_next",function(){
    if($(this).data('calendar-nav') == 'prev') {
        console.log('prev');
        alert($(this).closest('#calendar').data('calendar'));
    }
    if($(this).data('calendar-nav') == 'next') {
        console.log('next');
        alert($(this).closest('#calendar').data('calendar'));    
    }
});
```